# How do I count the number of elements in a Wix Database?

Tags: velo

I'm using Corvid by Wix and I created a data collection with multiple elements in the table. How can I count the number of elements from the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Most of your questions can be answered with a quick google search or reading the Corvid documentation: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference

For this specific question see .count() https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.WixDataQuery.html#count